# Sort character list in ascending order based on order of numerical list in r

Tags: r, sorting, plyr, lapply

I want to arrange a list with characters based on order/arrange results on another list.
For example, given a list `char`, and list of values (numbers) `mini`, I can get sorted char list:

```
sorted<-mapply(function(x, y) y[x], lapply(mini, order), char)
```

I want to use arrange/order that will sort `char` list based on ascending `min` list

(I want to have **ascendant alphabetical char when values in mini are same**).

Suggestions?

EDIT: dummy example

```
char <- list(A=c("dd", "aa", "cc", "ff"), B=c("rr", "ee", "tt", "aa"))
mini <- list(A=c(4,2,4,4), B=c(5,5,7,1))

char
$A
"dd" "aa" "cc" "ff" ...
$B
"rr" "ee" "tt" "aa" ...

mini
$A
4 2 4 4 ...
$B
5 5 7 1 ...
```

expected result:

```
sorted
$A
"aa" "cc" "dd" "ff"
$B
"aa" "ee" "rr" "tt"
```

Comment: This question would really benefit from a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)!

Comment: @Josh O'Brien Please see edit.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. I've edited it a bit to make it even more easily reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map(function(x, y) y[order(x, y)], mini, char)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply( names(char), function(nm) char[[nm]][order(mini[[nm]], char[[nm]])])
#------
[[1]]
[1] "aa" "cc" "dd" "ff"

[[2]]
[1] "aa" "ee" "rr" "tt"
```